# Update a column in R based on a vector

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to update the state for each regions present in the data.

Is there a more cleaner and efficient way to do this?
Because I also have to repeat the process for other states.

```
Seattle <- c("Bellevue","Richmond","Union-Lake")

in.Seattle <- data[which(data$region %in% Seattle),]
in.Seattle = list(in.Seattle$region)
data$State[data$region == unlist(in.Seattle)] <- 'Seattle'

structure(list(region = c("Bellevue","Richmond","Union-Lake", 
"Apatula","Broome"), region = c(2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), x = c(7513L, 30124L, 6807L, 
10191L, 84454L, 6057L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: How many vectors do you have like this `Seattle <- c("Bellevue","Richmond","Union-Lake")` ?

Comment: I have 8 vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(state = case_when(region %in% Seattle ~ 'Seattle', 
                           region %in% another_vec ~ 'another_vec', 
                           region %in% more_vec ~ 'more_vec', 
                           #Add more vectors
                           #......, 
                           #......))
```

where `Seattle`, `another_vec` and `more_vec` are the vectors. Also make sure you have unique column names in `data` since it is not advised to have columns with same name.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `fcase` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, state := fcase(region %in% Seattle, "Seattle",
                              region %in% another_vec, "another_vec",
                               ....
                               )]
```